# Passing an array via Ajax using json

Tags: ajax, json, spring, jsp, jackson

I have some textboxes generated dynamically through Ajax. I'm using [Jackson 1.9.8](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.8/jackson-all-1.9.8.jar) to parse json. I can retrieve the values of those dynamic textboxes using jQuery as follows.

```
var itemsArray=[];

$('input[name="txtChargeSize[]"]').each(function(){
    itemsArray[i][2]=$(this).val();                  
});
```

This can retrieve each element of the textbox array `txtChargeSize[]` one by one.

`itemsArray` is an array which already holds

The value of `weightId` on the `itemsArray[i][0]` position,

The value of `weight` on the `itemsArray[i][1]` position,

The value of `charge` on the `itemsArray[i][2]` position **which is the value of the textbox being assigned in the above code.**

---

I need to pass this array to Spring controller class to insert these values into the Oracle database. I'm trying the following.

```
var i=0;
$('input[name="txtChargeSize[]"]').each(function(){
    itemsArray[i][2]=$(this).val();        
    objectArray[i]=[["weightId",itemsArray[i][0]], ["weight",itemsArray[i][1]], ["charge",itemsArray[i][2]]];                  
    i++;          
});
```

It doesn't work as I expect. I need to pass something like the following.

```
[["weightId", 1], ["weight", 12.4], ["charge", 15.5]]
```

so that it can be parsed to `java.util.List<Object[]>`. I don't have precise knowledge of Javascript to accomplish this. How can I pass in this way the values held by `itemsArray` to Spring controller using json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i=0;
$('input[name="txtChargeSize[]"]').each(function(){
    itemsArray[i][2]=$(this).val();        
    i++;          
});
```

try javascript constructor method like this.

```
for(var i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++) {
   objectArray[i]= new createObj(itemsArray[i][0], itemsArray[i][1], itemsArray[i][2]);                  
}
```

and the constructor function is

```
function createObj(weightID, weight, charge) {
   this.weightId = weightID;
   this.weight = weight;
   this.charge = charge;
}
```

and finally if you want json string then use this

```
var str = JSON.stringify(objectArray);
alert(str);
```

Comment: I have tried it but it shows `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: Also tried using object notations directly like this one `items={
                      "weightId":itemsArray[i][0],
                      "weight":itemsArray[i][1],
                      "charge":itemsArray[i][2]
                  };` but it shows the same as in the previous comment.

Comment: @Tiny try JSON.stringify() method see my above answer, i have updated my it.